# CMake cannot find library on Windows

Tags: windows, cmake

I Have this CMake script to find a library:

```
#  FANN_FOUND - system has fann
#  FANN_INCLUDE_DIRS - the fann include directory
#  FANN_LIBRARIES - Link these to use fann
#  FANN_DEFINITIONS - Compiler switches required for using fann
if(FANN_LIBRARIES AND FANN_INCLUDE_DIRS)
    set(FANN_FOUND TRUE)
else()

    find_path(FANN_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES fann.h PATHS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/FANN/include)
    set( _libraries doublefann fixedfann floatfann )

    foreach( _lib ${_libraries} )
        string( TOUPPER ${_lib} _name )
        find_library(${_name}_LIBRARY NAMES ${_lib} PATHS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/FANN/lib")
    endforeach()

    set(FANN_INCLUDE_DIRS ${FANN_INCLUDE_DIR})
    message("${FANN_INCLUDE_DIR}")
    set(FANN_LIBRARIES ${FANN_LIBRARIES} ${DOUBLEFANN_LIBRARY}
    ${FIXEDFANN_LIBRARY} ${FLOATFANN_LIBRARY} )

    if( UNIX )
        set( FANN_LIBRARIES ${FANN_LIBRARIES} m )
    endif()

    if(FANN_INCLUDE_DIRS AND FANN_LIBRARIES)
        set(FANN_FOUND TRUE)
    endif()

    if(FANN_FOUND)
        if(NOT FANN_FIND_QUIETLY)
            message(STATUS "Found FANN:")
            message(STATUS "FANN_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${FANN_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
            message(STATUS "FANN_LIBRARIES: ${FANN_LIBRARIES}")
        endif()
     else()
         if(FANN_FIND_REQUIRED)
             message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find FANN")
         endif()
     endif()

mark_as_advanced(FANN_INCLUDE_DIRS FANN_LIBRARIES)
endif()
```

The script is called `FindFANN.cmake` and it is called by my main script with the `find_package()` command. Now I have also printed the directories `"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/FANN/lib"` and `"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/FANN/include"` and they are right.
However the libraries are not found and I cannot understand why.
In `"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/FANN/lib"` I have:

```
fanndouble.dll
fanndouble.lib
fannfixed.dll
fannfixed.lib
fannfloat.dll
fannfloat.lib
```

While in `"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/FANN/include"` I have `fann.h` among the others headers.

I know this is not the best portable script, but for now I just need it to work...

This is the exact output

```
$ cmake . -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" 
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.1
-- Check for working C compiler: c:/MinGW/bin/cc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: c:/MinGW/bin/cc.exe
-- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done 
-- Check for working CXX compiler: c:/MinGW/bin/c++.exe 
-- Check for working CXX compiler: c:/MinGW/bin/c++.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done 
CMake Error at cmake/Modules/FindFANN.cmake:91 (message): 
    Could not find FANN
Call Stack (most recent call first):
    CMakeLists.txt:30 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/Manuele/Documents/TicTacToe/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Here is my grep FANN CMakeCache.txt:

```
$ grep FANN CMakeCache.txt
DOUBLEFANN.LIB_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=DOUBLEFANN.LIB_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
DOUBLEFANN_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=DOUBLEFANN_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
FANN_DIR:UNINITIALIZED=C:/Users/Manuele/Documents/TicTacToe/FANN/
FANN_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=c:/Users/Manuele/Documents/TicTacToe/FANN/include
FIXEDFANN.LIB_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=FIXEDFANN.LIB_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
FIXEDFANN_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=FIXEDFANN_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
FLOATFANN.LIB_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=FLOATFANN.LIB_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
FLOATFANN_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=FLOATFANN_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND.
```

Comment: Exact output would be helpful, so we can see exactly which `message()` calls generate exactly which outputs. Also, the equivalent of `grep FANN CMakeCache.txt` would be helpful. --- On a different tangent, why are there *.lib / *.dll files in your CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR?

Comment: Because I am on windows and I want ship the whole thing in a single package. I would refactor my hierarchy, but shouldn't it work the same?

Comment: That was just a "smell". The basic concept with CMake is that you don't build / generate anything in the source tree at all (and let CPack do the packaging), so I was suspecting some more basic SNAFU there. So... could you copy the find_library() line and put a `message( "<...>" )` around the copy? So we can double-check just what exactly CMake is searching where exactly, to rule out any false assumptions as to the variables set at the time of the call?

Comment: On second thought... why is there no output from `message("${FANN_INCLUDE_DIR}")`, and what is this `FANN_DIR` doing in the cache?

Comment: Uhmm, you're right, I've lost something in the output, my fault, but I have to copy line by line, because otherwise I get everything on a single line...
FANN_DIR was set by me before and I did not clear the cache. Now I have clean the cache ad it disappeared.

Comment: `<find_library(DOUBLEFANN_LIBRARYNAMESdoublefannPATHSC:/Users/Manuele/Documents/TicTacToe/FANN/lib)> 
                                                           <find_library(FIXEDFANN_LIBRARYNAMESfixedfannPATHSC:/Users/Manuele/Documents/TicTacToe/FANN/lib)>
                                            <find_library(FLOATFANN_LIBRARYNAMESfloatfannPATHSC:/Users/Manuele/Documents/TicTacToe/FANN/lib)> `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK... it was there in plain sight all the time but it took that last `message()` output for me to actually realize it.

```
set( _libraries doublefann fixedfann floatfann )
```

And:

```
fanndouble.dll
fanndouble.lib
fannfixed.dll
fannfixed.lib
fannfloat.dll
fannfloat.lib
```

You see the problem? You're looking for the wrong library names. (`fanndouble` versus `doublefann` etc.)